# Mongoose .find() with multiple conditions, getting cast error using Javascript

Tags: javascript, mongodb, mongoose

I am trying to form a search query with mongoose.find() but I keep getting an error back and I am not sure why. It receives a query parameter and return the items whose name OR description contain the parameter.

Here is the code for the search function:

```
const searchQuery = async (q) => {
  try {
    const menuItems = await MenuItems.find({
      $or: [
        { name: { $regex: q, $options: "i" } },
        { description: { $regex: q, $options: "i" } }
      ]
    });

    return menuItems;
  } catch (error) {
    return error;
  }
};
```

Here is how information is being passed:

```
const searchQuery = async (req, res) => {
  try {
    const menu = await MenuItems.searchQuery(req.query.q);
    res.send(menu);
  } catch (error) {
    res.status(500).send(error);
  }
};
```

I am testing/calling it by the route "/api/menu/search?q=pizza" as a get request in postman and I keep getting this error:

```
{
    "stringValue": "\"search\"",
    "valueType": "string",
    "kind": "ObjectId",
    "value": "search",
    "path": "_id",
    "reason": {},
    "name": "CastError",
    "message": "Cast to ObjectId failed for value \"search\" (type string) at path \"_id\" for model \"MenuItems\""
}
```

code for menuItems:

```
const menuItemsSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
  name: {
    type: String,
    required: true,
    unique: true
  },
  price: {
    type: Number,
    required: true
  },
  description: {
    type: String,
    required: true
  },
  imageUrl: {
    type: String
  },
  updatedAt: {
    type: Date,
    default: Date.now
  }
});
menuItemsSchema.set("toJSON", {
  virtuals: true
});
// menu model
const MenuItems = mongoose.model("MenuItems", menuItemsSchema);
```

Comment: Can you share the code for `MenuItems`?

Comment: Added it to the post!

Comment: Also your route plz.

Comment: There is something wrong with your routes, You probably have another route `/api/menu/:id` whether router interprets the `/search` as `id`

Comment: I'll try creating updating the route and see if that helps

Comment: You have to change the order, you have to define `/api/menu/search` before `/api/menu/:id`.

Comment: Let me add it as an answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

*Since the comment fixed the issue, I added it as the answer.*

Seems the router interprets the path `/search` as `value`, You probably have another route something like `/api/menu/:id` where the router takes `/search` as the value of `:id`.

You have to change the order since the routes are being resolved in **top-to-bottom** order.

Add the `/api/menu/search` router before `/api/menu/:id`.

Answer (score -1):

The error you are encountering is due to the fact that Mongoose is trying to cast the `q` parameter as an ObjectId because it's being treated as if you are trying to find a document by its `_id` field. To resolve this issue, you should make sure that `q` is properly passed as a query parameter and that your `searchQuery` function is correctly handling it.

Here's the corrected code for your `searchQuery` function:

```js
const searchQuery = async (q) => {
  try {
    const menuItems = await MenuItems.find({
      $or: [
        { name: { $regex: q, $options: "i" } },
        { description: { $regex: q, $options: "i" } }
      ]
    });

    return menuItems;
  } catch (error) {
    return error;
  }
};
```

The issue here seems to be in how you are calling the `searchQuery` function in your route handler. You should pass the `req.query.q` parameter to the function, not try to access it as a property of the `MenuItems` model. Here's the corrected route handler:

```js
const searchMenu = async (req, res) => {
  try {
    const menu = await searchQuery(req.query.q);
    res.send(menu);
  } catch (error) {
    res.status(500).send(error);
  }
};
```

Make sure that your route is also defined correctly:

```js
app.get("/api/menu/search", searchMenu);
```

With these changes, your route handler will correctly call the `searchQuery` function with the `q` query parameter, and the error should be resolved. Now, you should be able to call the route "/api/menu/search?q=pizza" without encountering the ObjectId casting error.